# Sum a range from row, depending on cell matching value in another row

Tags: google-sheets, sum, match, google-sheets-formula

Sum a range using a value in the same row, that matches a value in the header row.

```
Header: 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |.... Sum from

Row:    10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |..... 2
```

In the example above, I want to sum the row values from Column 2 - column 4 (20+30+40)

If the Sum Row number was 3, I'd want to sum row values from Column 3 - Column 4 (30+40)

So I'm trying to start summing from the column number that matches the value in the sum from the column.

I've tried `sumif`

```
range = header range
criterion = sum from value
sum_range = row range
```

This only returns the value of the cell that matches the sum from the value
So if sum from is set to 2, it only produces 20, instead of 90(20+30+40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this worked out quite neatly in the end:

```
SUMIF($E$3:$N$3,">="&P4,E4:N4)
```

E3:N3 being the header row

E4:N4 being the row to sum

P4 being the cell with the value to match the header

the">=" can be adjusted depending whether you want to include the selected column or just those 'above'.

Comment: If this is solves your problem, accept the answer (with the little "V" sign) so that it's visible that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

use `ADDRESS` for that to construct range like:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, MATCH(B5, 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
              ADDRESS(3, COLUMNS(1:1),      4)))
```

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on a theme:

Using INDIRECT to define the range, and address to starting cell and ending cell. Uses information already available.

`=SUM(INDIRECT(address(row($B$3),B5+1,4) & ":" & address(row($B$3),B7+1,4)))`

---

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]